# Multiple "Forms Authentication" like cookies per application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

I am planing to implement a mult- tenant MVC application, where each tenant gets a "sub site" URL, so that rooting would look like:

```
www.mysite.com/{TenantId}/{Controller}/{Action}
```

When a user logs into the application, the login shall always be associated with a single tenant (there is no need for single sign on). However, it should be possible that he registers with two or more tenants in the same application. In such case, I need him to be able to simultaneously use both "sub sites".

As I understand it, the FormsAuthentication is using one cookie with a name specified in the web.config, visible in the code through `FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName`.

I was thinking about imlementing an approach similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9851665/1010666): implement custom cookie creation and checking (using `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt\Decrypt` for creating the tickets and then manually creating cookies with different names for different tenants). In this way the user could have several cookies, one for each tenant "subsite".

I am wondering, if this approach seems sensible/secure? I was dotPeeking the `FormsAuthentication` stuff and there is quite some additional stuff under the hood - with a reason I suppose. Also reading articles like [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WeirdTimeoutsWithCustomASPNETFormsAuthentication.aspx) (where the cookie expiration in the secure connection scenario was not handeled properly) makes one wonder, if custom security implementation is really the best way to go...

Alternative to several cookies might also be setting the cookie `Path` property. If I understand it correctly, the cookie shall be sent only with requests starting with {TenantId} if I set its path when creating it? Will FormsAuthentication know how to handle such cookies? When new ticket will be reissued, will the `Path` be respected?

And of course, all other suggestions are appreciated as well.

Comment: instad of www.mysite.com/{TenantId}/{Controller}/{Action} can you use subdomains for tenantiD?